# Are there any disadvantages or hazards to load all the firewall rules before loopback interface is initialized?

Tags: debian, iptables, ip6tables

I have fairly complex `iptables`/`ip6tables` rules affecting multiple interfaces. I would like to make sure, that firewall rules are always in place. As one can create rules even for (at that moment) non-existing interfaces(for example `iptables -A INPUT -i eth999 -j ACCEPT`), then I thought that I'll not associate the rules with a physical interface, but rather with `lo` interface which is always present:

```
# head /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
        pre-up /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/network/IPv4_fw_rules
        pre-up /sbin/ip6tables-restore < /etc/network/IPv6_fw_rules
#
```

Does this have any disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that lo is initialized first (it may happen to be configured thusly right now, but that doesn't mean it *has* to be that way and it may indeed be changed at some point in the future).

But why associate it with a network interface at all? Just add a custom init script or systemd service that you load before the network is initialized, and which runs the two commands to initialize the firewall. You're done. That's how I configure my firewalls at any rate...

Comment: Agreed, don't load the firewall before interface X. Load the firewall before touching the network at all. The firewall can create rules for interfaces that don't exist, and that's great for letting you load the firewall before configuring the network.